# Remove n duplicates from Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to make a way to find duplicates and remove the last n duplicate rows so for example if I have

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'brand': ['Yum Yum', 'Yum Yum', 'Indomie', 'Indomie', 'Indomie'],
})
```

and I want to remove 2 duplicates. It should return

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'brand': ['Yum Yum', 'Yum Yum', 'Indomie'],
})
```

As 'Indomie' is a duplicate and it's the last 2 duplicates in the data frame.

Comment: So you only want to remove n duplicates if there is at least n+1 times the same value?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I've understood your question right:

```py
x = df.groupby('brand').cumcount()
print(df[~df.index.isin(x[x > 0].tail(2).index)])
```

Prints:

```
     brand
0  Yum Yum
1  Yum Yum
2  Indomie
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html) and [`groupby.transform('size')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) for [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
n = 2
g = df.groupby('brand')
out = df[g.cumcount(ascending=False).ge(n) | g.transform('size').le(n)]
```

Output:

```
     brand
0  Yum Yum
1  Yum Yum
2  Indomie
```

##### how it works

```
     brand  cumcount  transform('size')  cumcount >= n  size <= n
0  Yum Yum         1                  2          False       True
1  Yum Yum         0                  2          False       True
2  Indomie         2                  3           True      False
3  Indomie         1                  3          False      False
4  Indomie         0                  3          False      False
```